# How to create a file manager like in MediaFire

Tags: php, ftp, file-manager

I would like to know how to create a file manager to upload, download, edit, etc.. files like in MediaFire, Rapidshare. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: 1. Procure some resources. 2. Write some code. 3. Profit!!! (or a FBI/Interpol takedown, but whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, you need the following:

- A structure of servers in the cloud.
- A good web application.

Now, it would be interesting to try to be a somewhat more specific in your question.

Regards!